# The function str() is not working and I do not know what to do

Tags: python, string

I have the code:

```
def rides(x):
   return list(str(x))
```

When I input the word hi without any quotes

It returns the error that hi is not defined

However when input integers or hi with quotes it works, but I need it to work for hi without quotes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're inputting the word hi?

Comment: If you don't put quotes around a word, it's a variable name.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x and the `input()` function? Change that to `raw_input()`.

Comment: Why do you need it to work with "hi without quotes"? You realize there are no actual quotes in your string, that is just how you write a string in source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your input is `hi` without quotes, it means you pass a variable named `hi` to your function.
If you don't define such variable before passing it to your function, your code will fail during it's evaluation with `NameError` error.